# Extending rst container to output extra div attributes

Tags: python, restructuredtext, docutils, pelican

I'm starting to use pelican with reStructuredText `rst` page format. I have custom javascript (jQuery) things that I'd like to control with div attributes like `data-default-tpl="basename"` with nested content.

What to extend and what. I've looked at `Directives` and `nodes`, but I just can't wrap my head around how to do it.

```
.. rstdiv:: class1 class2 
    :name: namessid
    :extra: thisIsMyextra

    .. rstdiv:: nested class3
        :name: nestedid  
        :extra: data-default-tpl="basename"

        some text

.. container:: This is normal rst container 
    :name: contid

    text
```

From rst to html with pelican.

```
<div id="nameisid" class="class1 class2" thisIsMyextra>
<div id="nestedid" class="nested class3" data-default-tpl="basename">
some text
</div>
</div>
<div id="contid" class="container This is normal rst container">
text
</div>
```

Comment: I've found a solution that is not perfect. I'll write it here as an answer as soon as I have enough spare time to clean it up.

Comment: Unless the new directive also works with other output formats, using raw HTML is simpler and allows to keep the sources standards-compatible. Alternatively, for simple string data, you may (ab)use the "class" attribute and adapt the javascript to react on a specific class value prefix.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about this ... [html rst directive](http://nikhilkalige.github.io/pelican-plugins-site/) plugin may work

Comment: Using html rst plugin misses the point and writing html is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.