# restructuredText How to include attributes inside a div

Tags: restructuredtext

Let's say I need something like this:

```
<a href="blah.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">blah</a>
```

How do I add rel and target in my rst file?

Comment: Looks like same question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824553/extending-rst-container-to-output-extra-div-attributes  -- no solution posted.

Comment: A similar question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11716781/623518). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11718325/623518) to this question.

Comment: Chris, thank you for the comment.  I am using raw html now, it is just  "clunky".  I may switch to markdown.